# With this code, how would I be able to print the value of the function, "shout"?

Tags: python

```
def shout(phrase):
    if phrase == phrase.upper():
        return ("YOU'RE TOO LOUD")
    else:
        return ("Can you speak up, I can barely hear you")

shout("I'M INTERESTED IN SHOUTING")
```

Comment: Also, please don't downvote this. I already had to wait 2 weeks to post this question because it, "wasn't well received by the community."

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592, and try to look for existing answers before posting a question. Questions get downvoted because they are judged not to be useful to the site. Please keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**; questions are supposed to help build an organized, searchable reference library.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap the function call in a print statement.

```
def shout(phrase): 
    if phrase == phrase.upper(): 
        return ("YOU'RE TOO LOUD") 
    else: 
        return ("Can you speak up, I can barely hear you")

print(shout('hello'))
print(shout('HELLO'))

# Can you speak up, I can barely hear you
# YOU'RE TOO LOUD
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace return with the print() function

```
def shout(phrase):
    if phrase == phrase.upper():
        print("YOU'RE TOO LOUD")
    else:
        print("Can you speak up, I can barely hear you")

shout("I'M INTERESTED IN SHOUTING")
```

Comment: Why the negative vote can any one pls explain what I did wrong?